# Google Analytics v2 iOS - session duration always 0.0

Tags: ios, session, google-analytics

I started using Goole Analytics v2.0beta3 for iOS native app. 
I start a session with the following code:

```
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
[GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXX-X"];
[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker = tracker; 
[tracker setAnonymize:YES];
BOOL res = [tracker trackEventWithCategory:@"cat" withAction:@"act" withLabel:@"label" withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
[[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch];
```

However, I don't know how to end the session and the session duration I get is always 0.0

Has anyone encountered this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would check and see if your trackers are set properly. My setup code is as follows

```
[GAI sharedInstance].debug = YES;
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:kTrackingId];
NSLog(@"what is tracker %@ / default tracker %@?", self.tracker, [GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker);
```

Where self.tracker is `@property (strong, nonatomic) id <GAITracker> tracker;`

I am getting correct session tracking information. Maybe try pulling out code until you find what is causing the issue?

Additionally a workaround could be something like this.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    appBecameActive = [NSDate date];
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    NSDate *appClosing = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval sessionLength = [appClosing timeIntervalSinceDate:appBecameActive];
    [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker trackTimingWithCategory:@"sessionLength"
                                                   withValue:sessionLength
                                                    withName:@"appWentToBackground"
                                                   withLabel:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Google Analytics v3 the session behaviour changed. If you're experiencing these problems with the latest version, check out my fix here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26882024/1485701